# How can I find out the date of the last change on a table in Teradata?

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table in Teradata that I suspect was changed.  Isn't there a quick sql command to get that info as in SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here it is

```
SELECT TABLENAME, LASTALTERTIMESTAMP 
FROM DBC.TABLES
WHERE DATABASENAME = 'My DB Name' -- OPTIONAL
ORDER BY LASTALTERTIMESTAMP DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

```sql
SELECT TableName, LastAlterTimeStamp 
FROM DBC.TABLES
WHERE DATABASENAME = 'Your DB Name' AND tablename='Your Table Name'
ORDER BY LASTALTERTIMESTAMP DESC
```